# OpenAPI V2 (Swagger) how to force client_id field to be URL encoded before being Base64 encoded an passed into authorization header?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I'm using springfox-swagger 3.0.0 to generate the Swagger UI (so I don't have much control over the Swagger UI code), and for my oauth2 authorization I've defined an application flow.

```
security: {
  key: "OAuth2";
  value: {
    type: TYPE_OAUTH2;
    flow: FLOW_APPLICATION;
    token_url: "/oauth2/token";
    scopes: {
      scope: {
        key: "api"
        value: "Grants access to api"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now my problem is that the client ids my system uses, contains colon ":" characters, which are also use to separate client id from client secret in the authorization header. This messed up the logic at the token endpoint.

```
authorization: Basic YXBpOjk1NmZkYmEzLWE1ZmEtNDk0MS1iZDAzLWY3NGY0ZmNhYjM1ZjpzWFNXVlBpcklSN1dsUkRvOG9lNFM2VTR3OEI0VFg4VUUwNm9QR2FyWmVn
```

If I URL encode my client id value before passing it to the client_id field in the swagger console, everything works ok.

```
authorization: Basic YXBpJTNBOTU2ZmRiYTMtYTVmYS00OTQxLWJkMDMtZjc0ZjRmY2FiMzVmOnNYU1dWUGlySVI3V2xSRG84b2U0UzZVNHc4QjRUWDhVRTA2b1BHYXJaZWc=
```

Any idea how can I instruct swagger to URL encode the client id field value before packaging it in the header?

Thanks

Comment: FYI according to the Basic auth [RFC 7617](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7617#page-5), _"a user-id containing a colon character is invalid"_. This means that your system needs to be fixed to generate client IDs without `:`.

Comment: In Swagger UI, do you supply the client ID via the Authorize dialog or via [`initOAuth`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/oauth2.md)?

Comment: I use  Authorize dialog to supply it.

Comment: @Helen I am 100% with you, the problem is that changing the existing client ids is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to fork [Swagger UI](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui) and implement the necessary change in your fork. Then, since you're using Springfox, you'll need to point it to your custom Swagger UI fork instead of the bundled version.

The code that constructs the `Authorization` header for OAuth requests lives here:
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/src/core/plugins/auth/actions.js

Tweak either the `authorizePassword` or `authorizeApplication` function (depending on your grant type) to percent-encode the `clientId`:

```js
Authorization: "Basic " + btoa(encodeURIComponent(clientId) + ":" + clientSecret)
```

Comment: Yes, I had this option in mind, but I was hoping to find a flag or something to control the UI behavior.